# Is this a JavaScript pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Is this a JavaScript pattern? The following code changes the test.get_context() object:

```
var test = {},
    value = {};

test.get_context = function(val) { 
  return function() { 
    return val; 
  } 
}(value);

var context = test.get_context();

context["test"] = 123;

//context = { "test": 123};

console.log(test.get_context());
```

but the following doesn't change it:

```
var test = {},
    value = {};

test.get_context = function(val) { 
  return function() { 
    return val; 
  } 
}(value);

var context = test.get_context();

//context["test"] = 123;

context = { "test": 123};

console.log(test.get_context());
```

In this case what is the difference between

```
context["test"] = 123;
```

and

```
context = { "test": 123};
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm wondering why in the first code snippet the output from the test.get_context() is object which has 'test' property with value 123 and why the second code snippet returns object with no properties. I've found this code and I'm curious. Shouldn't context["test"] = 123; do the same as context = { "test": 123}; ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context["test"]` sets `context.test` to `123`.

`context = { "test" : 123}` replaces context with a new object where `test` = `123`

It's the difference between updating of a value and replacing of a variable.

Your first version updates the object whereas the second overwrites it.

Answer (score 0):

> In this case what is the difference between
>
> context["test"] = 123;
>
> and
>
> context = { "test": 123};

The first sets a property of an object, the second *replaces* the object with a new one

Answer (score 0):

first one is array it is dynamically access. for example

```
var foo = 'index1';
var context = [];
var context1 = {'index1':'test'};
context['index1'] = 'test';

console.log(context[foo]) // it returns test
```

if i enter `console.log(context1.foo) // it return undefined error`

in object use can assess value as array format such as `console.log(context1[foo]) // it return test`